# Clarifying a parsing ambiguity in Java-like expressions with ANTLR 4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am writing a parser for a subset of Java-like expressions, and have found an ambiguity when parsing this code:

```java
(something) -x
```

since it could be parsed as `something - x` (binary expression) or `(something) (-x)` (casted unary expression).
Currently the parser favours the first option but I would like the second one.
The relevant parts of my parser look like this:

```
expression
   : LeftParen expr = expression RightParen # ParenthesizedExpression
   | id = Identifier # IdentifierExpression
   | op = (Minus | BitwiseNot) expr = expression # UnaryExpression
   | < assoc = right > LeftParen type = Identifier RightParen expr = expression # CastExpression
   | left = expression op = (Plus | Minus) right = expression # AdditiveExpression
   ;
```

Any ideas how to resolve this, ideally without eliminating the direct left-recursion?
Thanks.

Comment: Your `expression` rule currently doesn't accept a cast expression. I think if you add the following alternative to `expression` it will work: `LeftParen Identifier RightParen expression`

Comment: @BartKiers the second to last alternative is for  CastExpressions, might be a bit hard to see cause of the associativity.

Comment: Ah, right, I see it. I saw "< assoc = right >" and expected a power/exp rule :). Let me have another look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternatives in an ANTLR parser rule are tried from top to bottom. If you move your cast expression up, it will parse as expected:

```
expression
 : <assoc=right> LeftParen type=Identifier RightParen expr=expression   # CastExpression
 | LeftParen expr=expression RightParen                                 # ParenthesizedExpression
 | op=(Minus | BitwiseNot) expr=expression                              # UnaryExpression
 | left=expression op=(Plus | Minus) right=expression                   # AdditiveExpression
 | id=Identifier                                                        # IdentifierExpression
 ;
```

[image]

Comment: So it just depends on the priority of the *first* part? And it doesn’t matter that CastExpression is already above AdditiveExpression?

Comment: What is "first part"? I meant `<assoc=right> LeftParen type=Identifier RightParen expr=expression` is tried first, if that cannot be matched, `LeftParen expr=expression RightParen` is tried, then `op=(Minus | BitwiseNot) expr=expression` etc.

Comment: Just wondering cause my actual language has a lot more types of expressions and i’m not sure if i can raise CastExpression above ParenthesizedExpression without disrupting other stuff, they’re pretty far apart.

Comment: You must if you want `(something) -x` to be parsed as a cast expression.

Comment: In my original grammar Casts are already higher than subtraction and i would’ve thought that’s the priority that matters.